# Draggable and resizable for angular

Tags: angularjs, draggable, resizable

I know that jQueryUI has great widgets - draggable and resizable.
Are there any angular copies?

I don't want to use jQueryUI.

I want to make my modal draggable and resizable.

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes there are plenty. My favorite is 
https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop
and for resizable 
https://github.com/Reklino/angular-resizable

Comment: Great - and what about resizable?:)

Comment: angular-dragdrop is a wrapper for jQueryUI